# Best modeling for Counting on a one to many relationship query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, sqlperformance

I need help to choose a modeling solution.

I have a Table A with a record that relates to many others in table B. For example: Text (A) and Users who favorited it (B) or Product (A) x Reviews (B).

So... I like to know how many people favorited a text or reviewed a product. Ok, this is easy WHEN it's only one query for this situation, but can get complex when I start to join more and more tables. For example, to find usernames that faved or average of reviews + photos included in reviews + products without reviews at all, and also when there is a review related, but still blocked for moderation, and so on.

Still, it's possible to do a query for that, I know, but...

Is it a better solution If the Table A has a column just for counting how many records are related in table B ? Like Favorite_Count, review_count, review_avg, ...

This would "save a join" in a complex query in exchange for just a little bit more coding when someone favorite or unfavorite something. In the end the query would be easier to read and probably faster, right ?

What do you think ?

Comment: I shy away from storing aggregated data in tables this way. If your application misbehaves someone is going to have to say, hey these numbers don't match up, then you will need a process to make sure that they match up, next you will be managing how often the aggregator runs to correct bad application writes, in the mean time other applications are being bought online that come with their own host of problems for your aggregations. GROUP BY and INNER JOINS are your friends. Perhaps you could look into a read only database that reports can run off and flatten out your data there.

Comment: I see Kamil's point and in an extremely heavy read situation I could understand the complexity of managing the updated information into your Base table being thought of but I would side with Ross that typically it is an unneeded complication that just make for another point of failure.  Plus if you want both the detailed data and the aggregated techniques such as partitioned Window Functions and CROSS APPLY with proper indexes and optimization can keep the reads quick even in high demand scenarios

Comment: Yep, I agree a bit with you. But since the system will not get outside inputs, from API or so, it's really unlikely to have update errors. But it's a good point anyway.

But take a look in the real world example. This is what I'm trying to do and it's being hard: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40346096/designing-and-querying-product-review-system

I have to consider blocked and hidden reviews and products without reviews and, besides counting, also averaging the reviews (only the ones that are not blocked and hidden). 

Since I'm not a SQL specialist, it ishard to me. :(

Comment: I can have a update_count function (or stored procedure) for a product_id. Every update operation would trigger that function for that product_id.

Answer (score 0):

Data retrieval would be faster. Data insertion and updates would be slower. That's a trade-off. It depends on ratio reads to writes.

It would be of great value for you to investigate for example how StackOverflow does this. You can inspect the database schema [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new).

For instance, they put `AnswerCount` and `Tags` within the `Posts` table even though they could be easily retrieved every time with an additional join respectively to `Posts` (hierarchical structure) and `PostTags`.

In my opinion they went for it because this information is more often read than updated. Imagine how many users go through the post list, and how many actually click on every post. To build a post list on main page would require additional time to perform these joins every time someone refreshes it. That would be notable traffic, wouldn't it?

But then again it all depends on your case scenario. There is no "best approach" in this case.

Comment: Yes. Same case here. The extra code would be done just in the update. When moderator block / unblock / delete a review.  But the rading will be for every single product and also for a big, pageneted list of products. Favorites a bit easier... favorite or unfavorite would trigger the function.

Answer (score 0):

I have made good experiences with indexed views to this problem. These are very well suited for count calculations. In contrast to "normal" views, the records are stored as an index in the Sql-Server and they are automatically updated when an involved table is changed. However, these have some limitations, e.g. the schema binding is mandatory, you can use only inner joins, ... . I would create multiple indexed views and then query them. For more informations see on MSDN [Create Indexed Views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx).

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.v_productReviewsCount
  WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  SELECT T1.productId,
         COUNT_BIG(*) AS [count]
    FROM [dbo].[products] T1
         INNER JOIN [dbo].[reviews] T2
                 ON T1.productId = T2.productId
   GROUP BY T1.productId

GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ix_productReviewsCount_productId ON dbo.v_productReviewsCount (productId) 

GO
```